# Error using prepared statements in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, prepared-statement

The parameters aren't add to the sql string, what i'm doing wrong?

```
SqlCommand comando = conexao.CreateCommand();
comando.CommandTimeout = 7200;
foreach (SqlParameter parametro in parametros)
{
    comando.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parametro.ParameterName, parametro.Value));
}

comando.CommandText = cmdSql;
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = comando;

try
{
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.Message); }
conexao.Close();

return dt;
```

---

The Sql String, with the method who call the method above.

```
string cmdSql = "select top @quantidade *  from representante";
SqlParameterCollection sqlParameters = new SqlCommand().Parameters;
sqlParameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantidade;

return Persistencia.Persistencia.ConsultaComando(cmdSql, sqlParameters);
```

Comment: They are not supposed to be *added* to sql string as such.

Comment: I assume he means substituted into the command

Comment: You incorrectly using AddWithValue method. Try sqlParameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", quantidade)

Comment: Off topic, but I'd put that `conexao.Close();` in a `finally` block if I were you. Just generally good practice, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all helping but the solution is use `string cmdSql = "select top (@quantidade) *  from representante";` was answered in the MSDN: 
[Answer in MSDN BRASIL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/504/thread/4e6c9843-ef4d-4af3-8848-654f6c7e4d9a)

Answer (score 1):

Assign `CommandText` before adding parameters and show  `cmdSql` content.

Answer (score 0):

On the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) method you are trying to pass an enum as the parameter value.

Replace this:

```
sqlParameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantidade;
```

With this:

```
sqlParameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", quantidade);
```

Comment: I use this, and sqlParameters.Add("@quantidade", quantidade); and still nor working...